# Using the jQuery width() and height() methods

Tags: jquery, methods, height, width

Can you use the `.width()` and `.height()` methods to increase the height like `$('x').width('+=2px')` or `$('x').height('+=2px')`?

I couldn't find any information about this on the jQuery website, but I also haven't seen anything to suggest that this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These methods get and set the height or width of the elements.

`width()` or `width(val)`

Such approach as you say is only provided on `.animate()`

Sinan.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do something like this?

```
var el = $('x');
el.width(el.width()+2);
```

EDIT:
To clean it up, you can create a plugin, something like this (untested):

```
jQuery.fn.increaseWidth = function(amount) {
  this.width(this.width()+amount);
  return this;
};
```

This would allow you to do `$('x').increaseWidth(2)`

Comment: I mean, I knew you could do this, but it's really clunky and I thought there could be a shorter way to do this.

Comment: If you wanted to do it the way you're talking of, you could write a plugin to make a `$('x').increaseWidth(2)` function.

Answer (score 1):

No. The value you pass to `width()` is expected to be a [CSS length value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units). Pixels are assumed if you don't specify a unit.